# I want to get same row multiply times from select

Tags: mysql

Ok, got some table. for Example

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
id integer AUTOINCREMENT, --pk
name varchar(size)
);
```

Now I'd like to get rows by list of IDs, for example 5,6,and 10, so I do:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id IN (5,6,10)
```

That's obvious.
The point is I don't want the unique results only.
I mean if the select query would be something like:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id IN (5,9,5)
```

I'd like to get 3 rows as answer:
with name for id=5, with name for id=9 and again with name for id=5

How to do it, properly?

Comment: Why would you like to get the same result twice?

Comment: Nobody ever needs to do this :-( at least, not in mysql

Comment: actually it's just one time shot for statistic.
I got like 1k+ id's and I was told that if id repeat - the row should repeat also. 
Not my decision.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a `join` instead of `in`:

```
select tn.name
from table_name tn join (
    select 5 as id union all 
    select 9 union all 
    select 5) t on tn.id = t.id
```

Or you could use `union all` by itself:

```
select name from table_name where id = 5
union all
select name from table_name where id = 9
union all
select name from table_name where id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing multiple times the same query with a different id each time and "joining" the result of each query with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id = 9
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM table_name WHERE id = 5
```

Note that it is important to use `UNION ALL` and not only `UNION` to get the result you want: with `UNION`, MySQL would remove duplicated rows, and this would be exactly the same result as using `IN (5, 9, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement should work fine:

```
 SELECT `name` FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` IN (5, 6, 10)
```

Of course, you will need to allow duplicate values for your `id` column. If `id` is a primary key or has unique index then there isn't a way for your table to have two rows with `id`=5.

Comment: `where id in (1,1,1)` is the same as `where id in (1)` -- both will return the same result.  To repeat the result (to duplicate it), you cannot use `in`.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I did something like:

```
SET @ids = '4,5,5';
create temporary table if not exists tmp_ids ( oid integer);
    SET @S1 = CONCAT("INSERT INTO  tmp_ids(oid) VALUES ('",REPLACE((@ids), ",", "'),('"),"');");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

now I just used tmp table to join during select. After that I drop the tmp table.
THX for help guys.